# Using ThreeJS StereoEffect and Raycaster

Tags: javascript, virtual-reality

Has anybody used ThreeJS StereoEffect and Raycaster together for collision detection (in stereo view).  In standard full screen view I can easily check if a Vector2 in the middle of the screen colides with an object in my scene.  When I switch on the stereo effect I in effect get 2 scenes, and the collision detection stops working, but I am not really sure how to proceed.  Should I create two new vector2d objects, one for each view - help :) ...

Comment: were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late, but ...

I encountered a similar problem, I eventually found the reason. Actually in StereoEffect THREE.js *displays* the meshes on the two eyes, but in reality is actually adds only one mesh to the scene, exactly in the middle of the line left-eye-mesh <-> right-eye-mesh, hidden to the viewer.

So when you use the raycaster, you need to use it on the **real** mesh on the middle, not the illusion displayed on each eye !

I detailled here how to do it 
[Three.js StereoEffect displays meshes across 2 eyes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41540403/three-js-stereoeffect-displays-meshes-across-2-eyes)

Hopes it solves your problem !

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [StereoEffect.js](https://github.com/anhr/three.js/blob/5d0101b8273af239e6080de53e93d615a1885b65/examples/js/effects/StereoEffect.js) file in your project for resolving problem. See [example](https://raw.githack.com/anhr/three.js/raycaster_stereo/examples/webgl_raycaster_stereo.html) of using.