# Three.js StereoEffect displays meshes across 2 eyes

Tags: three.js

I have a THREE.js scene using StereoEffect renderer. However, when I add new meshes to the scene, they are displayed across the two eyes instead of being duplicated for each eye. I believe THREE.js is supposed to do it automatically and I don't have to duplicate them myself ? (I tried duplicating them but it is a lot of annoying calculation and I could not manage it)

My meshes are actually transparent planes, and I add a DOM element on the top of them to have a flat display.

[Illustrating Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUo0W.png)

Answer (score 1):

OK I finally found it ! I tried putting back on a texture (not invisible) on my meshes and I discovered the problem.

When we use StereoEffect and we see that our mesh is duplicated on both views, it is actually an *illusion* : THREE.JS puts an image there, but the *actual* object is invisible, put exactly at the middle of the two images !
See image here : [explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRIXe.png)

If you use raycaster for instance, it will tell you there's not an instersection where you *see* the mesh, but at the center of the line from left image to right image ! Same for mesh.position.

So what I did was keep an invisible texture, and create two div tags that I placed symmetrically around the mesh position :

```
var middleX = window.offsetWidth/2;
//left div
if(this.element.id.indexOf("-2") == -1){
    var posL = coords2d.x - middleX/2;
    this.element.style.left = posL + 'px';
    //Hide if gets on the right part of the screen
    if(posL > middleX) this.element.style.display = 'none';
}
//right div
else{
    var posR = coords2d.x + middleX/2;
    this.element.style.left = posR + 'px';
    //Hide if gets on the left part of the screen
    if(posR < middleX) this.element.style.display = 'none';
}
```

That gives the *illusion* that my mesh is there, put it is just empty divs.

Then, to check if someone clicks on my mesh, I do the opposite : I go back to the *real* position of the mesh before sending it to raycaster !

```
function hasClicked(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var clientX,clientY;

        //GET REAL POSITION OF OBJECT
        var middleX = window.offsetWidth/2;
        //Right screen
        if(e.clientX>middleX){
            clientX = e.clientX - middleX/2;
        }
        //Left screen
        else {
            clientX = e.clientX + middleX/2;
        } 
        clientY = e.clientY;  //Keep same Y coordinate

        //TRANSFORM THESE COORDS ON SCREEN INTO THREE.JS COORDS
        var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
        mouse.x = (clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = -(clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

        //USE RAYCASTER
        raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(arrowManager.storage);

        if (intersects.length > 0) {
            //It works !!!
        }
    }
```

And it works perfectly fine !! Hope this can help someone else, I was getting really desperate here ;)